# Recycling views in Backbone.JS

Tags: javascript, optimization, backbone.js

I work on a Backbone app, which utilizes a lot of view. I fell into the (usual I think) trap of instantiating a Router (sort of, the main controller) which is responsible for clearing out the views, instantiating new ones, and filling them with data. I say trap, because although JavaScript has a built-in garbage collector, one will quickly start noticing how the usability of the app gets hampered by the many unused views which still reside somewhere in memory.

I wish there were a way to recycle those views. I thought that this would be as easy as calling initialize() on the view with a new model, and then rerender. This is unfortunately not as easy.

Also, one would have to kinda "destroy" the view handles, for example, event handlers and stuff...

What would be a good practice to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Once a view has been removed from the `DOM` it will be garbage collected.  Unless of course you cache it.  If you do cache a view and remove it from the `DOM`, all event handlers are garbage collected as well. Unless you use something like jQuery's `detach` method, which will preserve the event handlers.

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

If you want to recycle a view, simply cache it in a variable.

Inside your `router`'s init method, do something like this:

```
this.views = {};
```

Then whenever a route is called check if the name of the view is available in the cache and if it is, use that, otherwise create a new one.

```
someRoute: function () {
   var view;
   if ( _.has(this.views, 'someRouteView') ) {
        view = this.views.someRouteView;
   } else {
        view = new SomeRouteView;
        this.views.someRouteView = view;
   }
   // You have a view now
}
```

Again, if you don't create a new view, you will have to use something like jQuery's `detach` method to preserve event handling.

Comment: what about initializing? Should I specifically call a custom "constructor" function to reinitialize it? Just calling "initialize" won't do the job

Comment: You never call `initialize` directly on views in backbone. Unless your simulating inheritance within another view's `initialize` method.  The view will already be initialized when it's cached. Calling `new View` runs the init method.

Comment: The only real benefit of using a cached view is performance. You won't have to rerender the view each time the route is run.

Comment: but it can have a negative impact also. cache too many and you will suffer issues (especially in ie). Better to detach, remove and clean-up and render new each time rather than keeping things around just in case.

Comment: I agree.  Depending on your application size and the number of views that being cached, you're better of recreating each when it is needed.

Comment: what, really? Should I skip caching for the time being?

Comment: If your views don't parse through a lot of data, yes.